# Excel AVERAGEIFS else statement

Tags: excel

I'm trying to perform an AVERAGEIFS formula on some data, but there are 2 possible results and as far as I can tell AVERAGEIFS doesn't deal with that situation.
I basically want to have an ELSE inside it.

At the moment I have 2 ranges of data:

- The first column only contains values 'M-T' and 'F' (Mon-Thurs and Fri).
- The second column contains a time.

The times on the rows with an 'F' value in column 1 are an hour behind the rest.

I want to take an average of all the times, adjusting for the hour delay on Fridays.

So for example I want it to take an average of all the times, but subtract 1 hour from the values which are in a row with an 'F' value in it.

The way I've been doing it so far is by having 2 separate results for each day, then averaging them again for a final one:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(G3:G172, B3:B172, "M-T")
=AVERAGEIFS(G3:G172, B3:B172, "F")
```

I want to combine this into just one result.
The closest I can get is the following:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(B3:B172="M-T",G3:G172,((G3:G172)-1/24)))
```

But this doesn't produce the correct result.

Any advice?

Comment: I understand you are having a table of hours for two separate ranges for "M-T" and "F' . In that case multiply the average figure for "M-T" with counts of readings obtained with Countif function for "M-T". Similarly for "F" range. Then you can obtain weighted average by summing the above multiplications with sum of counts of total readings. If this is not the case then can you upload or edit your question to put up a sample data of your tables for better understanding.

Comment: Edited the main question. Basically just want to get an average of all the values, but reduce the value of some cells if the value next to it is an 'F'.

Comment: Is cell value in the form of 19:17:43 or numeric format or a string. Can you give an example of time value format.

Comment: The time format is h:mm AM/PM. Formatting isn't an issue. It's the formula to average it that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the details regarding time format. I have posted my answer after verifying the results and have appended a snapshot showing working on a sample data, intermediate and final results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just combining the two averageifs. No idea why I didn't just do that from the start:

```
=((AVERAGEIFS(G$3:G171, $B$3:$B171, "F")-1/24)+AVERAGEIFS(G$3:G171, $B$3:$B171, "M-T"))/2
```

Comment: We have seen your sample data. It is not in line with your question. The times on the rows with an 'F' value in column 1 are an hour behind the rest. I want to take an average of all the times, adjusting for the hour delay on Fridays. Your sample data  average time for Fridays is 3:45 PM while for M-T it is 2:56PM. This is as per your calculation and is in contradiction to your question. Another contradiction is The first column only contains values 'M-T' and 'F' (Mon-Thurs and Fri). Whereas your sample data contains X and FX. If your base data changes no body can help you.

Comment: Another point is your proposed formula is also not working for all the sample cases. It is giving error except for the first case. You also have not entered Array Formula correctly. We request you to review the sample data in line with your Original Post Otherwise We may have to consider down Voting your Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       =(SUMPRODUCT(G3:G172)-(COUNTIF(B3:B172,"=F")/24))/COUNTIF(B3:B172,"<>""""")
```

[image: Snapshot showing formula on sample data]

**EDIT**
Explaining various steps in the formula as per sample data in the snapshot.

- SUMPRODUCT(G3:G17) sums up all the value from G3 to G17. It gives a
  value of 4.635416667. This after formatting to [h]:mm gives a value
  of 111.15
- OP desires that Friday time be one hour less.  So I have kept one hour less for Friday's in the sample data. Similar SUMPRODUCT on H3:H17 leads to a value of 4.510416667. This after formatting to [h]:mm gives a value
  of 108.15. Which is exactly three hours less for three occurrences of Fridays in the sample data.
- `=COUNTIF(B3:B17,"=F")` counts the occurrences of Friday's in the B3:B17 range which are 3 occurrences.Hence 3 hours have to less. These hours are to be represented in terms of 24 hours hence the Function `COUNTIF()` value is divided by 24. This gives 0.125. Same is the difference of 4.635416667 and 4.510416667 i.e. 0.125
- Demonstration column H is for illustrative purposes only. Infact Friday accounted values that is 108.15 in sample data has to be divided by total data points to get the AVERAGE. The occurrences of data points are calculated by `=COUNTIF(B3:B17,"<>""""")` with a check for empty columns.
- Thus 108:15 divided by 15 data points give 7:13 in the answer.

  **Revised EDIT Based upon suggestions by @Tom Sharpe**

@TomSharpe has been kind enough to point the shortcomings in the method proposed by me. `COUNTIF(B3:B172,"<>""""")` gives too many values and is not advised. Instead of it `COUNTA(B3:B172)` or `COUNT(G3:G172)` are preferable.  Better Formula to get AVERAGE as per his suggestion gives very accurate results and is revised to:

```
 =AVERAGE(IF(B3:B172="M-T",G3:G172,((G3:G172)-1/24)))
```

This is an Array Formula. It has to be entered with CSE and further cell to be formatted as time.

Comment: It's not quite getting me the result I'm expecting, but I'm seeing your logic right up to the last countif. Can you explain that please?

Comment: @Andrei Sevtsenko I am editing my answer explaining each step for the benefit of others also If they become interested in this solution. Further I have uploaded the working file which you can tweak in the meanwhile. [excel averageifs statement question dt 24-06-2016](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jun_2016/excel%20averageifs%20statement%20question%20dt%2024-06-2016.xlsm)

Comment: @Andrei Sevtsenko I have edited my post with explanation of various steps in the formula. Please go through it.

Comment: I tried it and COUNTIF(B3:B172,"<>""""") gives too many values, although it works fine with COUNTIF(B3:B17,"<>"""""). Suggest COUNTA(B3:B172) or COUNT(G3:G172). Also original formula edited to =AVERAGE(IF(B3:B17="M-T",G3:G17,((G3:G17)-1/24))) seems to give right answer if entered as an array formula and formatted as time?

Comment: So what is going wrong with original formula is that all blank cells would be set to -1/24 and it would need a separate condition for these.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks for your kind indulgence. I shall edit my formula accordingly after a quick review.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks a lot. Your suggested formula works like a charm and give exact result. I am editing my answer mentioning reference to your suggestions.

Comment: @Andrei Sevtsenko I have revised my answer as per valid suggestions received from Tom Sharpe. This is similar to one mentioned in your question. How come it did not behave well at your end?

Comment: @skkakkar Sorry I took a while to reply, was a bit busy.
Not sure why it's not behaving, but I'm attaching a version of the document (redacted) with all the versions you've suggested.
The green row is the expected values I'm looking for. None of the formulas seem to match up.

Also worth noting that the B column has other values other than M-T and F, but they're supposed to be ignored. This may actually be what's causing the issue.

[Testing document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7jimhbd1zr5tdc/Testing%20Document.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: @Andrei Sevtsenko Your sample data is not in line with your original post. If you want solution for this data, please put a new question. Further You have not CSE entered an Array formula.

Answer (score 1):

If your column of `M-T` and `F` is named `Day` and your column of times is named `TIME` then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Day="M-T")*TIME + (Day="F")*(TIME-1/24)))/COUNT(TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to create a separate column that maps the time column and performs the adjustment there.  Then average this new column.

Is that an option?

Comment: It can be, but mostly as a last resort. This is a part of a report that has to be sent out and needs to be formatted well without extra data. I'd much prefer to get it done in a single formula if possible.

Comment: There's always the option of hiding the extra column and putting the result back into the visible column.  I have spreadsheets like this where most of the work is done in hidden columns.  All the user sees are the input fields and the summary data, most of the sheet is hidden away from them.  I think this make the spreadsheet much easier to understand and maintain, rather than trying to do everything in one fancy, unreadable formula.